# jquery tab switcher

Tags: jquery

I have the below script:

```
var SwitchTabs = function(container, tabs, activeclass, which) {
var tabContainers = $(container + ' > div');
var index = 0;
var tabnum = (which) ? parseInt(which) - 1 : 0;
tabContainers.filter(':eq(' + tabnum + ')').css({'display':'block'});
$(container + ' > ' + tabs).find('a').click(function(){
    index = $(this).parent().index();
    tabContainers.css({'display':'none'}).filter(':eq(' + index + ')').show();
    $(container + ' ' + tabs + ' ' + ' a').removeClass(activeclass);
    $(this).addClass(activeclass);
}).filter(':eq(' + tabnum + ')').click();
}

$(function(){
SwitchTabs('div.tabs', 'ul.mostpouplar', 'active', 1);
});
```

Mark up:

```
    <div class="tabs rrmodule">
    <h3>Popular</h3>
    <ul class="mostpopular">
        <li><a href="#">Most Viewed</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">Most Commented</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div>
    Some content - tab 1
    </div>
    <div>
    Some content - tab 2
    </div>
    </div>
```

The above (as per the code) should should set a class to the first anchor element and show the 1st DIV on page load. Then DIVs are shown and anchor class is set according to the click. I am using jquery 1.4.4. For some reason click does not work, neither the onload setting the class and showing the DIV don't work! I think the code is quite straightforward. Can someone help me with this please.

Thanks,
L

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues, you should not use the JavaScript keyword `which` as a parameter name.  Also, you misspelled `ui.mostpopular` as `ul.mostpouplar`.  Here it is working:

http://jsfiddle.net/magicaj/yFFaJ/2/

Answer (score 0):

You want have something like that : http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs use jQuery UI.
Or jQuery Tools: Tab: http://flowplayer.org/tools/tabs/index.html.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution JSFiddle::** https://jsfiddle.net/incorelabs/mg6e4ren/

Implementing Tabs is really simple, I have modified the HTML for your question a bit. Removed the anchor tags coz they are not needed.

> HTML

```
<ul>
    <li class="tab-switcher" data-tab-index="0">test1</li>
    <li class="tab-switcher" data-tab-index="1">test2</li>
    <li class="tab-switcher" data-tab-index="2">test3</li>
    <li class="tab-switcher" data-tab-index="3">test4</li>
</ul>
<div id="allTabsContainer">
    <div class="tab-container" data-tab-index="0">Some content - 1</div>
    <div class="tab-container" data-tab-index="1" style="display:none;">Some content - 2</div>
    <div class="tab-container" data-tab-index="2" style="display:none;">Some content - 3</div>
    <div class="tab-container" data-tab-index="3" style="display:none;">Some content - 4</div>
</div>
```

> HTML De-Mystified

1. Add the "tab-switcher" class to each "li" element.
2. Give a "data-tab-index" attribute to each "li".
3. Add the "tab-container" class to each Tabbed Container. Also provide a "data-tab-index" attribute to each container which corresponds to the "data-tab-index" attribute on the "li" element.
4. Show only the container you want visible, hide the others using "display:none".
5. Provide a parent container for all the content of the tabbed containers. In this example this is the "allTabsContainer" div.

> jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var previousActiveTabIndex = 0;

    $(".tab-switcher").on('click', function () {

        var tabClicked = $(this).data("tab-index");

        if(tabClicked != previousActiveTabIndex) {

            $("#allTabsContainer .tab-container").each(function () {

                if($(this).data("tab-index") == tabClicked) {

                    $(".tab-container").hide();
                    $(this).show();
                    previousActiveTabIndex = $(this).data("tab-index");
                    return;

                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

> jQuery De-Mystified

1. The click listener on the "tab-switcher" gets initialised on "document.ready".
2. The variable "previousActiveTabIndex" keeps a track of the previous active tab so that if we press on the same tab again and again, it can be ignored.
3. We run an EACH loop on the "tab-container". This is done to know which tab should be displayed. If the "data-tab-index" data attribute on each matches, we display that tab.
4. We keep the value of the "data-tab-index" saved in "previousActiveTabIndex" which helps us keep a track of the previous tab which was clicked.

**If there are doubts or if someone has suggestions, do comment on the post.**